# Is item/data cache necessary for each site in a Sitecore instance?

Tags: configuration, caching

As per the below link - cache configuration - is this cache to be configured

- from site definition point of view for each sites

or

- configured in a single Sitecore instance where it has to be based on one single entry which is holding the configurations for all the sites in the same instance.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configure-item-and-data-cache-values.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caches you are referring to here are database caches. These are configured per database and not per site. This means you set the per instance for all sites but it also means all sites share the cache.

There are other caches that are being set per site as well (e.g. the html cache https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configure-html-component-cache-values.html)

If you want more information about these caches operate, you might want to check this question and its answers: [What is the difference between the item, prefetch and html caches?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/395/237)

Comment: Thanks @gatogordo for the immediate answers this was helpful. I also would like to know is there a place/config to define sitecore data item which needs to be cached. i know sitecore html caching can be achieved via rendering properties, but is there any setting like making sure the datasource item is been cached ?

Comment: Added some info to the answer, but to answer your specific question: a datasource item will be cached by Sitecore. You don't need to do anything to achieve that.